# Flux through square sheet due to point charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

[image]

The above picture requires us to find the flux through the square sheet, due to a proton.
Treating the sheet as one plane of a Gaussian cube, I found the flux using,
$$\text{Flux}= \frac{E*dA}{6}$$
This gives the answer $9.6 \frac{nNm^{2}}{C}$
However, the actual answer is $3.01 \frac{nNm^{2}}{C}$

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what is $dA$?  Do you mean $d^2$? .

Comment: I would guess dA refers to infinitesimal area.

Comment: The flux should be $\int \vec{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}A$ or $E \cdot d^2 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly then the flux through a complete box would be $\Phi_{total}=q_{encl}/\epsilon_0$ By symmetry one side would be $1/6$ of this, or 
$$
\Phi_{side}=q_{encl}/{6\epsilon_0}=\frac{1.6\times 10^{-19}}{6\times 8.85\times 10^{-12}}=3.01\times 10^{-9}\, .
$$
The distance between the point charge and the plane or the area of your box do not enter in the calculation of $\Phi_{total}$ since the net flux is just the enclosed charged divided by $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: d is used in the calculation, as d^2. And (d/2)^2 is used in the calculation of E in place of r^2.

Comment: @AntaraKulkarni  My original answer was incorrect but I've corrected it now.